# Java agent for reading beans

Tags: java, spring, javaagents

I have received task to create tool (using java agent or other way) to read all started/running application Spring beans and parameters and save it in CSV file. Later these files would be compared to see changes between different app versions.

Can you recommend how it can be realised using java agent?

Comment: https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter

Comment: @esprittn thank you for recommendation. But if I understand correctly this tool needs to be added to application pom.xml and it runs together every time application is running. In my case tool should not be running all the time but only for saving beans configuration(classes, methods, arguments) on every application version. Then these saved configuration files can be compared by client before migrating from one version to another(as I understand it).